# Datagridview Datos a textbox error

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Al dar click en una fila seleccionada esta me envía los datos en los `TextBox` pero me envía en cada `TextBox` el texto de `DataGridViewTextBoxCell { ColumnIndex=2, RowIndex=2 }` alguien que pueda ayudarme ?

Comment: Te recomiendo que expliques un poco mejor tu problema, agregando un código un poco más completo también, sino es literalmente imposible ayudarte

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Debes mostrarnos el código que estás usando para poner el valor en los textboxes, pero viendo lo que te da es muy probable que no estes accediendo a la propiedad `Value` de `DataGridTextBoxCell`